# cy.intercept() not stubbing API in Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-intercept

When I use `cy.intercept()`, the API does not stub.

```
cy.intercept("GET", `${API}farm/list`, {
  body: {
    statusCode: 200,
    message: "Request successful",
    result: seededFarmList,
  },
});
```

I am importing the fixture file like this:

```
import { seededFarmList } from '../../../../../fixtures/farm';
```

My API response looks like this:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200, 
  "message": "Request successful", 
  "result": [ 
    { "id": 1 "farmName": "ABCD", },
    { "id": 2 "farmName": "EFGH", }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you stubbing the API ? Are you passing a custom response body through fixtures ?

Comment: yes. I am passing a custom reponse through fixture

Comment: What is the name of your fixture file (.json) ?

Comment: No. It is .ts. I am using typrescript (seededFarmList.ts).

Comment: Having the same issue here. Stubbing with a fixture, local variable or direct value inside intercept() is not working for me. Did you find anything?

Comment: Any new idea?
I have this issue after cypress 6 
The intercept will not detect the XHR if I pass the HTTP method to it but without the HTTP method, it will detect the XHR although it cannot return the fixture as the result and the other problem is that the actual request will be sent to the server.

Comment: I haven't, Olafvv

Comment: Is seededFarmList a fixture file? Please show how it is loaded.

Comment: Marion,  It is a fixture file. I import the file like this:                                                    import { seededFarmList } from '../../../../../fixtures/farm';                                               
 My API response looks like this:                                                
       {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "Request successful",
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 1
      "farmName": "****",
     
    },
    {
      "id": 2
      "farmName": "*****",     
    },

Comment: Thanks @sofina, I added your comment to the question for clarity.

Answer (score 26):

Make sure the network intercept is registered before the application makes the api call. Notice the `cy.intercept` is set up before `cy.visit`.

```js
it('is registered correctly', () => {
  cy.intercept('/todos').as('todos')
  cy.visit('/')
  cy.wait('@todos')
})
```

In the following example `cy.intercept` is set up after `cy.visit` and this might fail.

```js
 it('is registered too late, this might fail', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.intercept('/todos').as('todos')
    cy.wait('@todos')
  })
```

Comment: Additionally if you're writing Component testing, make sure to run `intercept` before `mount`

Comment: This fixed the issue in my case  - "Make sure the network intercept is registered before the application makes the api call". thx

Answer (score 8):

I'm not entirely sure why it's not stubbing (presume you mean the server response is getting through?).

In any case, the stubbed response pattern is now a lot more complicated, and it's going to trip up a lot of people.

Here's my interpretation of the documentation,

In `cy.route(method, url, response)`, response documented as **body**

> Supply a response **body** to stub in the matching route.

In `cy.intercept(method, url, routeHandler?)`, routeHandler is a more complicated beast.

> routeHandler (string | object | Function | StaticResponse)

but **object** and **StaticResponse** are both objects - Cypress makes the distinction by looking at the object keys, according to this

> If an object with no StaticResponse keys is passed, it will be sent as a JSON response **body**.

StaticResponse keys are

```
{
  fixture?: string
  body?: string | object | object[]
  headers?: { [key: string]: string }
  statusCode?: number
  forceNetworkError?: boolean
  delayMs?: number
  throttleKbps?: number
}
```

Since you are sending **statusCode**, your object *is* a StaticResponse, and therefore message and result should be moved to body,

```
cy.intercept('GET',
  `${API}farm/list`,
  {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {
      message: 'Request successful',
      result: seededFarmList
    }
  }
);
```

---

IMO they've over-engineered things a little - the fallback from StaticResponse to object (depending on keys) is a bit unnecessary.

---

I just found an example in the sample spec `network_requests.spec.js` (added on Cypress 1st run).

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io/commands/network-requests')
})

...

let message = 'whoa, this comment does not exist'

// Stub a response to PUT comments/ ****
cy.intercept({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: '**/comments/*',
}, {
  statusCode: 404,
  body: { error: message },                         // stub returns above message
  headers: { 'access-control-allow-origin': '*' },
  delayMs: 500,
}).as('putComment')

// we have code that puts a comment when
// the button is clicked in scripts.js
cy.get('.network-put').click()

cy.wait('@putComment')

// our 404 statusCode logic in scripts.js executed
cy.get('.network-put-comment').should('contain', message)
```

Comment: This doesn't work in NextJS with SSR since the requests are made on the server. Cypress has no access to this.

Comment: Luckily there is no mention of NextJS NuxtJS or SSR in the question.

Comment: Looking at the life cycle documentation for cypress intercept finally got me understanding how to use the routeHandler Function mentioned here. For my problem I had to use `req.reply({ statusCode: 200 })` https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Interception-lifecycle

Answer (score 8):

I managed to get stubbing working with the pattern @eric99 gave,

```
cy.intercept(
  'GET',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: {
      message: 'Request successful',
      result: ['my-data']
    }
  }
)
.as('typicode')

cy.visit('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/')
cy.get('#run-button').click();

cy.wait('@typicode')
.then((interception) => {
  console.log('interception', interception)
})
```

The page shows the stub information,

```
{
    "message": "Request successful",
    "result": [
        "my-data"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Richard, what format is your data, the one you assigned to the result? I did the same way you did, but still not working

Comment: The format of the data is not relevant to whether or not the the `cy.intercept()` function stubs (except when it has a syntax problem like a missing comma between properties). Any well-formed object on the `body` property should be returned to the app. It looks like your `seedFarmList` is problematic.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue before then I found out that it was caused by CORS policy.

There are some solutions to overcome this issue:

- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Set-chromeWebSecurity-to-false
- Both front-end and back-end should be on the same origin; e.g., HTTP://localhost:1000

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are using getServerSideProps() or any of the Next's other SSR methods, but if you are, cy.intercept() will not work as the API call is done server-side.  You will have to use nock to intercept and mock any server-side API calls done within getServerSideProps() or any similar server-side methods in Next.

Comprehensive reading on this subject here:
https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/mock-network-from-server/

Answer (score 0):

I did this, and it stubbed the API.

```
cy.intercept(
          {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `${API}farm/list`
          },

          {
            body: {
              statusCode: 200,
              message: 'Request successful',
              result: seededFarmList
            }
          }
        ).as('loadData');
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress doesn't seem to resolve the route matcher params if you use template literals in the route matcher pattern.

Does not work:

```
cy.intercept('GET', `/.*${mybaseUrl}\/something\/.*/`)
```

(even though the pattern is valid, and it even shows up right in Cypress!)

There are 2 ways I have found to make it work.

1. Explicate the url with the routematcher parameter:

```
cy.intercept(
          {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `.*${mybaseUrl}\/something\/.*`
          })
```

2. Use RegExp constructor

```
cy.intercept('GET', new RegExp(`.*${mybaseUrl}\/something\/.*`)
```

It does look like a bug in Cypress, but these are two very acceptable workarounds.